# Angular promise boolean JSON deserialization

Tags: angularjs

I don't understand how the JSON deserialization works when dealing with `Boolean` type.

```js
myapp.factory('Probe', function($resource) {
   return $resource('/webapp/network/v1/probes/:id/:action', { id: '@id' }, {
       testConnection: {method: 'POST', params: {action: 'testConnection'}},
       update: {method: 'PUT'}
   });
});
```

The call:

```js
Probe.testConnection({probe: probe}).$promise.testConnection(probe).then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

The console displays `e {0: "t", 1: "r", 2: "u", 3: "e", $promise: Object, $resolved: true, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}`. I am expecting just a true or false.

The backend is a Spring-based webapp returning a `ResponseEntity<Boolean>`

Comment: Sending "true" back is invalid JSON, and angular is getting confused as a result. Try wrapping it in an object.

Comment: I wrapped the object with a `Map<String, Boolean>` and it works. Thx

Comment: I was faced with the exact same issue. So I created a wrapper class ad return it: return new ResponseEntity<ValueResource>(new ValueResource(hasDependencies), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
 public class ValueResource { private Object value;

    public ValueResource(Object value) {
     this.value = value;
    }  public Object getValue() {
  return value;
 } }

Comment: Switching from `$resource` to `$http` worked for me.  It was a simpler solution than trying to bend `$resource` to play nice with a `Boolean` response.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use **transformResponse** to modify your result, like:

```
myapp.factory('Probe', function($resource) {
return $resource('/webapp/network/v1/probes/:id/:action', { id: '@id' }, {
    testConnection: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            action: 'testConnection'
        },
        transformResponse: function(data, headers) {
            return {data:data};
        }
    },
    update: {
        method: 'PUT'
    }
 });
});
```